# Sequelize missing FROM-clause entry for table Postgres, after adding the limit and offset

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, backend

i have a sequelize query like this. however, when I add limit and offset there is an error like this.
what should i do?

```
const courses = await DB_COURSES.findAll({
    attributes: ["id"],
    include:[
      {
        model: DB_COURSETRANSACTIONS,
        attributes:["coursePurchasedId"],
        include:[
          {
            model:DB_COURSES,
            as: 'coursePurchased',
            include:[
              {
                model: DB_COMPANIES,
                as: 'buyerByCompany',
                attributes:["id"]
              }
            ],
            required: true
          }
        ],
        required: true
      },
      {
        model: DB_COMPANIES,
        as: 'authorByCompany',
        attributes: ["id"]
      }
    ],
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0
  })
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMhNp.png)
[ERD table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldx3P.png)

I want like this:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9M0w.png)